# Add new environment to an existing release-build

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have release build that has been kicked off already, this build was kicked-off it went through QA and staging environment successfully, the users were happy with the app on both these environments. I then added the last environment that is production. Now my question is, is there a way of getting the current build to see that there is an extra environment added, at the moment it looks like the production deployment does not exist yet I know its there, here is the screenshot of the prod environment[image] that was added

The below screen illustrate that the app deployed succcessfully to the other environments but the prod environment does not appear, the area highlighted in red is where I am expecting my prod environment to appear [image]

I understand queuing or kicking off a new build would make the prod environment appear but I wonder if is there a way to let the current release that there is new environment added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The pipeline is locked in when the release is created. You can create a new release using the same build that you'd previously deployed to lower environments.  That will pick up the production environment that you added to the release definition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think already running releases will have PROD environment aded